# Azure AD connect to multiple forests

Tags: active-directory, azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm trying to set up Azure AD Connect with a sync from 3 forests to 1 tenant. However, I'm struggling to add the forests in the AD Connect wizard.

I'm working with the following domains:

intranet.city.com with Netbios name "INTRANET"
intranet.pdwxcity.com with Netbios name "INTRANET"
city.com with Netbios name "CITY"

In the "Connect your directories" page, I was able to add the "parent" (company owning the tenant) domain intranet.city.com but I couldn't add the other domains. All the required ports are open. I am getting the following errors (depending on the format of the credentials; Netbios name, full domain name, UPN, etc):

The provided user was not found in the directory. Specify a valid domain account
OR
The specified forest does not exist or cannot be contacted
OR
The specified domain does not exist or cannot be contacted

Any idea what the problem could be? Is the fact that they have similar Netbios or top level domains a problem?

Please note that I am working with the hosts file for name resolution to the other domains. I don't know if this is a problem or not.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: see if this helps you. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-topologies#multiple-forests-single-azure-ad-tenant

Comment: hi Bruno Faria, thanks for the reply. I checked that out already and it doesn't take me any further. But thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by manually creating SRV records for the other domains. DNS forwarders were not in place because of some particular setup at the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a name resolution issue to me. What entries do you have in your host file? why aren't you using DNS? you need to be able to resolve the SRV records of the domains you want to connect to. Can the server you have installed Azure AD Connect on resolve those records? what DNS Server is it using?

Comment: Hi Michael Brown, thank you for your reply. In the hosts file I have added the domain name and the domain controller of the intranet.pdwxcity.com domain. The city.com domain controllers are resolvable through DNS (using the DC/DNS of intranet.city.com - where the AD Connect server is installed). How can I check if the SRV records can be resolved?

Comment: If there is separate DNS server in each forest, then on the DNS server the AD Connect is using, you can add Conditional Forwarders for other two forests/domains. You can refer to the following article for Conditional Forwarder. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794735%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Jozef: just to check if the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the follow-up. It hasn't been resolved yet. Will know for sure if it's resolved on the 3th of May. In the mean time I can say that I'm also convinced now that it's a DNS issue and that configuring forwarders will probably resolve it. I will update this thread as soon as I've implemented the forwarders. Thanks again!